# double slash comment in the middle of a statement

Tags: c#

I want to comment out one line in a multi line fluent statement. For example:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning)
    //.MinimumLevel.Override("Hangfire", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(serilogLevelSwitch)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();
```

I pressed "comment out the selected lines" on the third line and Visual Studio just added double slash at the beginning of the line.

Is double slash in the middle of a statement valid? I don't get compile error, intellisense makes the line green, and that part got disabled. But will I get into trouble in the future? Is this a good practice?

Comment: It's valid. You probably don't want to be in the habit of leaving commented-out code everywhere, but it won't cause any problems.

Comment: *Is this a good practice?* commenting out code with no explanation is not good practice. If the code is wrong remove it. If the code should only apply in certain situations, control it with a variable or compiler directive. At the very least comment why the code is commented out so that your coworker/replacement/future-self can make a judgement as to whether the commented out code can be removed or if it's the source of the weird bug they're now getting with some edge case. `//commented this out because though it solves solves rare x it introduced another bug of ... ; can live with x for now`

Comment: (And then maybe also put a TODO or #warning of "one in a million times this fails with xyz but..." and put it in your rainy day issue tracker)